# recovering a lost record in CMS

Tags: content-management-system

A record has been deleted from a CMS that I am using called ePublisher. Is there anyway of recovering that deleted record from ePublisher itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on whether the ePublisher is using [soft delete](http://databaserefactoring.com/IntroduceSoftDelete.html) or [hard delete](http://databaserefactoring.com/IntroduceHardDelete.html). If soft delete, then you can trace back the latest edit, and revert the delete. If hard delete, then good luck to you. Either way, you have to access the underlying database to do the revert operation. I don't think ePublisher allows you to revert your operation in the ePublisher UI.

To find out whether it's soft or hard delete, you have to look at the database schema, is there a `IsActive` column besides the entry? If yes, then the ePublisher users soft delete, if not... then probably no.